# How do you use array refs in Perl threads?

Tags: multithreading, perl

I want to keep the hash with array reference in the thread. I'm getting the following error.

The following code is executable as it is. You will see the error message like

> Invalid value for shared scalar at ./thread1.pl line 25.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.18;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my %myhash :shared;
my $stop_myfunc :shared = 0;
my $count = 0;
my $listref;

my @a = ('1','2');

@$listref = @a;

%myhash = (
    rootdir => "<path>/junk/perl",
    listref => $listref,
);

sub my2ndfunc {
    print "I am in the thread\n";
    $count++;
    $myhash{$count} = 0;
}

sub myfunc {
    while ($stop_myfunc == 0) {
        sleep(1);
        my2ndfunc();
    }
}

my $my_thread = 0;
$stop_myfunc = 0;
$my_thread = threads->create('myfunc');

$myhash{'test'} = 0;
sleep(3);
print Dumper \%myhash;
$stop_myfunc = 1;
$my_thread->join();


1;
```

I tried array ref declared as `:shared`, but not helped.

Is there something I am missing here. I am not able to think of any other alternative here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The *array* needs to be shared, not the reference to it.

Comment: Note that the array in question isn't `@a`, but the anonymous one created by `@$listref = @a;`.

Comment: changing array ref to just array works for me. but still need to understand if arrayref is not at all supported or any other way to handle the refs in threads.

Comment: Re `*but still need to understand if arrayref is not at all supported*", Again, no problem with array refs, as long as they are references to shared arrays. You need to make the array shared. The docs show how, and now so does an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [threads:shared](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads::shared#share-VARIABLE):

> Shared variables can only store scalars, refs of shared variables, or refs of shared data

You have to use `shared_clone` to use any other data type.

```perl
my @a = ('1','2');
my $listref = shared_clone(\@a);

%myhash = (
    rootdir => "<path>/junk/perl",
    listref => $listref,
);
```

Since you presumably won't need the original copy of the data structure you're sharing, it's better to just define it within a `shared_clone` statement in the first place.

```perl
my %myhash :shared = (
    rootdir => "<path>/junk/perl",
    listref => shared_clone( ['1', '2'] ),
    inventory => shared_clone( { additional => [qw/pylons doritos mountain_dew/] ),
);
```

Comment: This is helpful, what if the scenario is like this. $myhash is a ref. As refs cannot be shared directly, and hitting following error on the following code. 

Invalid value for shared scalar at 

my $myhash :shared = {
    rootdir => "<path>/junk/perl",
    listref => $listref,
};

One workaround is to convert ref to %myhash. Any idea how the ref $myhash can be used in this scenario

Comment: Same answer from worked for my above query, thank you @lordadmira.

Comment: Just remember that the thing the reference points to must be shared.